# Shell script remotely

Tags: linux, shell

I have one script running on server and doing some job on other server
I have many scp commands and ssh commands, this is why each time I have to enter the remote server password at each remote command.
is there any way to establish ssh connection between the servers so I type the remote password only once?
thanks

Comment: Post an example. You can `ssh server -c "command1; command2; command3; command4; .... "`

Comment: you can set up SSH keys to avoid password, you can also use expect, https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html, to fill password automatically, also can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to setup an ssh [config](https://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) together with ssh keys. In a nutshell the config will hold an alias for one or more remote servers.

```
ssh remote_server1
ssh remote server2
```

While your config file will look something like this:

```
Host remote_server1
Hostname 192.168.1.12
user elmo
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/remote.key
...
```

If an ssh config file is not for you (although I can highly recommend it), you can use [sshpass](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) as well.

```
sshpass -p 't@uyM59bQ' ssh username@server.example.com
```

Do note that the above does expose your password. If someone else has access to your account, the `history` command will show the code snippet above.